# Android - DisplayMetrics Resolution issue when using HDMI

Tags: android

I have a GoogleTV device from Sony which is connected to a Full-HD TV (1920x1080) using HDMI. I use the following code to calculate the target display dimensions of the TV.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
//dm.widthPixels
//dm.heightPixels
```

which works fine and I get 1920 and 1080 px respectively.

Now for the issue. When the I connect the GoogleTV box to a different TV with different dimensions, it still shows 1920x1080 whereas the resolution is much different.

Is there something I need to extra for getting the new resolution ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding it within onSizeChanged, something like below may work:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
{
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    ScreenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    ScreenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
}
```